# Freebase video id

Tags: sitemap, google-tv, freebase

Relating to the video:id tag for video sitemaps value 
Where do I find the freebase id that needs to be put in as the value?  For example, CNBC.  I was looking on the CNBC page on the freebase website and couldn't find it... http://www.freebase.com/view/en/cnbc.

Comment: This is a a programming question and should be re-opened. It relates to the Google TV and Freebase APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess, but it is maybe **/en/cnbc**

When you make a request to the Freebase API, it returns **/en/cnbc** as the id.
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=cnbc

So I suspect your tag will look something like this

```
<video:id type="freebase">/en/cnbc</video:id>
```